# How can I separate the implementation of the Default trait for a structure in another file?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have about a hundred fields in the structure, so I want to store the struct definition and the data in separate files.

Specifically, I want to keep the definition in a file, and the `default` implementation in another file. I want to access the `default` implementation from `main.rs`. I am not sure how to achieve it.

**Directory tree**

```
.
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   ├── config.rs
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── config_types.rs
│   └── main.rs
```

**config_types.rs**

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Config {
    a: u8,
    b: u8,
}

impl Config {
    pub fn new(a: u8, b: u8) -> Self {
        Config { a, b }
    }
}
```

**config.rs**

```rust
#[path = "./lib/config_types.rs"] mod config_types;

use config_types::Config;

impl Default for Config {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Config {
            a: 0b0000_0001,
            b: 0b0000_0000,
        }
    }
}
```

**main.rs**

```rust
#[path = "./lib/config_types.rs"] mod config_types;
#[path = "./config.rs"] mod config;

use config_types::Config;

fn main() -> ! {
    let config = Config::default();
}
```

The error I am getting:

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `default` found for struct `config_types::Config` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:64:26
   |
64 |     let config = Config::default();
   |                          ^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `config_types::Config`
   | 
  ::: src/./lib/config_types.rs:2:1
   |
2  | pub struct Config {
   | ----------------- function or associated item `default` not found for this
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `default`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `Default`
```

If I move the default implementation into `config_types.rs`, the error goes away.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: *Please* don't use `#[path = ...]` unless you already know what you are doing. It's not the best way of including code in 99.9+% of the cases.

Comment: Putting the structure and the implementation in different files (without a good reason) is non-idiomatic Rust. I'd encourage you to _not_ do this.

Comment: You seem to be falling into the trap of "I really want my files to be here, here, and here on the disk" and ignoring where idiomatic Rust would place it. This is not a fruitful direction, and you are setting yourself up for a bunch of heartbreak.

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment. I have about a hundred fields in the structure, it's easy to maintain a separate file and improves the readability of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove the `#[path]` attributes. Instead, use regular modules and re-export as needed.
2. Make the fields public in the entire crate.

**src/main.rs**

```
mod lib {
    pub mod config_types; // Point 1
}
mod config;

use lib::config_types;  // Point 1
use config_types::Config;

fn main() {
    let config = Config::default();
}
```

**src/config.rs**

```rust
use crate::config_types::Config;  // Point 1

impl Default for Config {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Config {
            a: 0b0000_0001,
            b: 0b0000_0000,
        }
    }
}
```

**src/lib/config_types.rs**

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Config {
    pub (crate) a: u8,  // Point 2
    pub (crate) b: u8,  // Point 2
}

impl Config {
    pub fn new(a: u8, b: u8) -> Self {
        Config { a, b }
    }
}
```

---

> I have about a hundred fields in the structure

That makes it sound like this is an autogenerated file. See the [code generation example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-script-examples.html#code-generation) for build scripts for other ideas on how to solve this. If it's not an autogenerated file, I don't see how separate files make anything easier.

I'd avoid creating a module called `lib` because that tends to be too confusing with the common `lib.rs` file.

If I was going to do this myself, I'd flip it so that the generated file is included into the hand-edited file:

**src/main.rs**

```
mod config;

use config::Config;

fn main() {
    let config = Config::default();
}
```

**src/config.rs**

```
include!("autogenerated.rs");

impl Config {
    pub fn new(a: u8, b: u8) -> Self {
        Config { a, b }
    }
}

impl Default for Config {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Config {
            a: 0b0000_0001,
            b: 0b0000_0000,
        }
    }
}
```

**src/autogenerated.rs**

This file probably *wouldn't* exist in the `src` directory if it were generated!

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Config {
    pub a: u8,
    pub b: u8,
}
```

Note that these no longer need to be public.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is what I was looking for. Also, thanks for correcting my path. I am absolutely new to rust. So, this is going to help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The line `mod config_types;` declares a *new* module. Even though you point them to the same file via `#[path = ...]`, they will result in different declarations of `Config`:

- `crate::config_types::Config`
- `crate::config::config_types::Config`

You then try to use `Default` for one when it is actually defined on the other.

So only use one or the other:

- remove `mod config_types;` from `config.rs` and import it via `main.rs` instead via `use crate::config_types;`
- remove `mod config_types;` from `main.rs` and export it from `config.rs` via `pub use config_types::Config;`

Using `#[path = ...]` is very rarely appropriate. For example, the one for `config` is totally unnecessary and will work without it. I recommend going over the [Managing Growing Projects with Packages, Crates, and Modules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-00-managing-growing-projects-with-packages-crates-and-modules.html) chapter of the Rust Book, which does a good job of explaining modules and how to import/export items properly.